# How to override the AbpUserConfigurationController?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I don't know the underlying principle of the AbpUserConfigurationController? How does it inject into the aspnet core DI container? Why can't it be seen on the Swagger page? I'm using the aspnetboilerplate Premium Startup Templates.

Comment: Injection happens based on naming conventions. Controllers can be POCO too (without inheriting from controller base class). Controllers in assemblies outside of the web project won't be included unless you add it via AddApplicationPart (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I know, I can't find out the place where aspnetboilerplate Premium Startup Templates add AbpUserConfigurationController using AddApplicationPart? Can you tell me the place? Thanks.@Tseng

Comment: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/AbpAspNetCoreModule.cs#L47-L78

Comment: I have seen this part of the code, but I can't see the relationship between `AddApplicationParts` and `AbpUserConfigurationController`?@Tseng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To override `AbpUserConfigurationController`**

you can use the approach mentioned in [aspnetboilerplate/#3296(comment)](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3296#issuecomment-384540373)

**To understand how Abp inject controller into AspNetCore project**

It is explained by [@tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455493/tseng) , controller can be added via `AddApplicationPart` of `ApplicationPartManager`.

There are a few places that Abp uses `ApplicationPartManager` to include additional controllers.

1. In `Abp.AspNetCore`, as pointed out by [@tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455493/tseng), at [AbpAspNetCoreModule#L47-78](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/AbpAspNetCoreModule.cs#L47-L78), the implementation here is to include Controller created in the `Abp.AspNetCore` assembly.
2. In the downloaded template, you can look for `*WebCoreModule.cs` under `*.*.Web.Core` project. The following code snippet is another place that Abp converts all the application services in the `MyProjectApplicationModule` assembly into controllers.

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore()
      .CreateControllersForAppServices(
          typeof(MyProjectApplicationModule).GetAssembly()
      );
```

Also you take a look at [AbpAspNetCoreConfiguration.cs#L47-L55](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Configuration/AbpAspNetCoreConfiguration.cs#L47-L55) where the `ControllerAssemblySettings` is being updated.

Take note that `CreateControllersForAppServices` is called in `PreInitialize()` of `AbpModule` and `AddApplicationParts` is called in `PostInitialize()` of `AbpAspNetCoreModule`.

Therefore, the `ControllerAssemblySettings` used in the method `AddApplicationParts` of `AbpAspNetCoreModule` has already contains all the controllers to be added via `ApplicationPartManager`

**To understand why `AbpUserConfigurationController` not showing up in swagger-ui**

In short, *conventional routing* is not supported by `Swagger`, see [swashbuckle-apiexplorer-and-routing](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#swashbuckle-apiexplorer-and-routing).

`TokenAuthController` showed up in the `swagger-ui` because it is decorated with `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` (*attribute routing*)